# Change sort order of commerce orders

Tags: 7, commerce

In admin of the Commerce module, Orders (Store > Store Orders) are currently being sorted by '*order number*' and I think "alphabetically" because they have a strange order like so:
842, 754...287, 146, 1370

How would I go about changing the default view to sort by '*Created*' date to ensure that the latest orders are always at the top of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit next: Administration » Structure » Views » Orders (admin/structure/views/view/commerce_orders/edit/admin_page)

FORMAT > Format:Table | Settings 
Click Settings. In radios buttons select own default order field.